# Why the mongodb database take more space after removing documents

Tags: mongodb

Before I remove data, the database takes 25.5G space, has 413562171 documents.

Then I execute the following operating：

db.collectionName.remove( { xxx: "xxx" } )

This operating deletes 165540416 documents and the database takes 25.8G.

I am confused why it takes more space after removing so much data.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove documents, MongoDB doesn't free the space automatically (it supposes this space can be reused for new documents)

You can free the space using `repairDatabase` command: as `db.repairDatabase()` from a mongo shell; or as `mongod --repair` (mongod should not be already running when use this way)
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/repairDatabase/

Please, take into account that the repairDatabase requires free disk space equal to the size of your current data set plus 2 gigabytes, and obtains a global write lock, will block other operations until it has completed

**Little addition:**

If you use WiredTiger Storage Engine you can also use `compact` command instead `repairDatabase`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/

The WiredTiger storage engine is the default storage engine starting in MongoDB 3.2